# How do you know when @Published var changes inside a @EnvironmentObject?

Tags: swiftui

I have this

```
class GlobalVariables: ObservableObject, Equatable {
  @Published var searchText:String = ""
}
```

this is used by ContentView.

`searchText` changes when the user types on the search bar.

Inside another view, I have this:

```
@EnvironmentObject var globalVariables : GlobalVariables
```

On that class I need to detect when `searchText` changes (didSet?), but how?

Sorry I am new to SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.onReceive`, like

```
struct OtherView: View {
   @EnvironmentObject var globalVariables : GlobalVariables

   var body: some View {
      Text("some view")
        .onReceive(globalVariables.$searchText) { newValue in
           // do anything needed here
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Fatastic thanks but I have to say, SwiftUI is like all over the place, very disorganized and confuse, with everything spread. The idea is good but it poorly implemented.